# How do I filter out human users only from list of all azure AD users? (no service accounts or rooms)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the Graph API (beta) and getting a list of all users from /users. As expected, this returns a list of all users including service accounts and conference rooms. Is there any reliable way I can filter only human employees out from this list?

I've tried using the properties "assignedPlans" and "assignedLicenses" to try and pinpoint human users, but it doesn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no such a property that well distinguishes human and other user type.

If you want to distinguishes room account, you can refer to [this Microsoft Graph API: findRooms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to get the room accounts and exclude them from your initial user list.

BTW, what do you mean by "service accounts"?

Comment: There seem to be other applications that need an account to operate in the environment correctly, so they've been facilitated by the creation of a service account which acts as a gateway to the environment for these third party apps.

Comment: Got it. If so, I am afraid there is no good way to distinguish them. It is highly recommended that you add them to a specific group when creating employee accounts. After that you just need to get group members to find all the employee accounts.